# Using Docker image without Entrypoint to serve R plumber API

Tags: r, dockerfile, plumber

I use the [geospatial rocker2 image](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned2) to deploy Rstudio for development and a Shiny app for production. By using a single image, I have a consistent package library, credentials and database connections. I would like to use this same image to serve a plumber API.

Using the standard [plumber.R example](https://www.rplumber.io/) and the [standard plumber Docker example](https://www.rplumber.io/articles/hosting.html#default-dockerfile) I have tried to serve it as follows:

```
docker run -v `pwd`/app/plumber.R:/plumber.R --name plumber --restart=unless-stopped \
                   -p 8000:8000 my_rocker2_fork/geospatial Rscript /plumber.R
```

Success, kind of. The plumber.R file is clearly being sourced, but it is not being "plumbed":
[image: Terminal output]

Another issue is that the container continually restarts (this is the output of docker ps - please ignore the node.js container running):
[image: Output of docker ps]

One more oddity is that port 8000 isn't shown. Sometimes it is, sometimes it isn't. I think this is related to the restarting behaviour.

My code isn't plumbed, because I don't have the Entrypoint that is standard in the [rstudio/plumber Dockerfile](https://github.com/rstudio/plumber/blob/master/Dockerfile), and I don't think I want this Entrypoint, as it may cause issues with Rstudio Server and the Shiny app that are also in this image. Therefore, I think it is probably optimal to "plumb" by expanding the Rscript command at the end of my Docker run statement:

```
docker run -v `pwd`/app/plumber.R:/plumber.R -p 8000:8000 my_rocker2_fork/geospatial \
                   'Rscript pr("/plumber.R") %>% pr_run(port = 8000)' &
```

However, this fails because of all the special characters (like the pipe operator). How can I serve plumber code with an arbitrary Dockerfile without an Entrypoint?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple! Call a script that sets the plumbing in motion, e.g.

```
docker run -v `pwd`/app/plumb_start.R:/plumb_start.R -p 8000:8000 my_rocker2_fork/geospatial \
               Rscript plumb_start.R
```

Where plumb_start.R contains:

```
pr("plumber.R") %>% pr_run(port=8000)
```

Make sure that you also expose port 8000 in the Dockerfile.